# Do we know how the different functions are selected when Wnt pathway is activated?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-signaling, pathway

The Wnt signaling pathway is [said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wnt_signaling_pathway) to allows multiple functions:

- Axis patterning
- Cell differentiation
- Cell proliferation
- Cell fate specification
- Cell migration

But how are these functions "distinguished by the cell" when the Wnt signaling pathway is activated by the receptor on the cell's surface? I mean, do only specific environment conditions (and if yes, do we know which one?) triggers the duplication of the cell, or its differentiation? Or is there a co-signalling that triggers the cell into one or the other mechanism?